# Best Database Practice regarding to keeping "snapshot" of foreign reference

Tags: sql, database

I'm fairly new to database design and would like to know some good approaches to the following scenario. Let say I have sales system that has a relation for keeping track of unit price of products and another to keep track of sales order. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    ProductID INT NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER(
    OrderID INT NOT NULL,
    OrderQuantity INT NOT NULL,
    ProductID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductID)
);
```

What is the best approach to still retain original information of the unit price after changing the UnitPrice on a particular product since I want ORDER to act as a sales record/history. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally each Order has its own price, which is usually the price of the product at the time of the order.  But different customers might have different prices, etc.